# Check for a property which was conditional added

Tags: typescript

I am trying to check for a conditional added property.

First all my definitions.

```
interface AnimalProperties {
    legs?: number
    hands?: number
}
  
interface DogProperties extends AnimalProperties {
    legs: number
}

type Animal<Properties extends AnimalProperties> = (
  Properties & 
  (Properties["legs"] extends number ? {walkspeed: number } : {}) & 
  (Properties["hands"] extends number ? {fingers: number} : {})
)

type Dog = Animal<DogProperties>;
```

The function canWalk checks for a conditional added property. How do I have to define function canWalk to check if the animal has a walkspeed?

```
let lassie: Dog = {}

function canWalk(animal: Animal<AnimalProperties>){
  if(animal.legs && animal.legs > 0 && animal.walkspeed > 0) return true;
  return false;
}

let lassieCanWalk = canWalk(lassie);
```

Typescript error on `animal.walkspeed` is `Property 'walkspeed' does not exist on type 'AnimalProperties'`

The Playground can be found here: [TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwApQD2ADtGMBAM7IDeAUMo8jhAOaUD8AXMiAK6YARtAZMAFnBAATTj35CRAX1F1QkWIhQARQqwIkyFahAAekadXRZc+0lHJVaoxi3ZyBwqHWV0wAT1I0DGwcAB5bQ0dTcxkg63wiOwdKAD5kAF5kAApRCPsjZAAyZFEsvOSAbQAiV0oqgF1kaIgLXg9oZA5aAHdcAGtKUggpdwUoZEVkHhpFAEoiksYyxMjKaokLBqazFtj5T07aGFBWaEpRz0npubpZul8A7V0MuJDQnT0V-KoUgG57lhgZhwSiUCg8D4vGi1HgAFgANMhejgBkMRshYYp-nQYHwQAhyIQQMgEJIAOr9LKSeI8KxvOk2L7JFKzeiMYAwKnBXAAOlqRWK1JCfLY1DSAAYBcghbzkaiIMNkBL5lAIGA+FBiWAoHwIP9GKr1ZrkPAcJQ9d4AWrgaCKABhcn9F6kkAUlFZHAgsEQWa-IA)